# Muting all browser audio with javascript

Tags: javascript, audio, global, mute

I'm doubting this is even possible but it would be a big help.

I'm throwing together a portfolio and bringing in external sites via ajax to fit in nice little "3D" containers.

The problem is.. 2 of them have audio that autostarts (yes, generally a bad practice but they work on these 2 pages).

One is html5 audio - simple enough, just `.volume` and set it to 0.

The *other* is an `.swf.` file. I'd like to mute ALL of the elements on the page, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Do you control the swf's? If so, turn it off. Or add a variable to the swf take a parameter to control the volume (e.g. `http://example.com/myswf.swf?volume=0`).

Otherwise, it's not possible.

Comment: Hmm.. that could work. At least it doesn't destroy the existing page. Thanks!